# Convert image into bytes to store in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Can anybody tell me that how to convert an image (stored in a file path) into bytes to store in a database?

Comment: Vote to close - sorry, i simply can not make any sense out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to store the path as bytes? Why don't you just store it as a string? Unless you mean you want to store the image data as bytes in the database, in which case, look into the [Image](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=tsql+Image&meta=#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=tsql+working+with+Image+datatype+site%3Amsdn.microsoft.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=ec7c6fa3d8dbef8b) data type.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an image stored locally to bytes you can use `IO.File.ReadAllBytes()`. To convert an image on the web you can use `Net.WebClient.DownloadData()`. The `IMAGE` data type is going away in SQL Server, so use `VARBINARY(MAX)` to store it.

#### Code:

```vb
Dim url As String = "http://example.com/image.png",
    file As String = "c:\image.png"

Using connection As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("your connection string"),
    saveImage As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.saveImage", connection)

    connection.Open()
    saveImage.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

    'use only one of these
    saveImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imageData", New Net.WebClient().DownloadData(url)) 'get file from url
    'saveImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imageData", IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file)) 'get file locally

    saveImage.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

#### Procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[saveImage] ( @imageData AS VARBINARY(MAX) )
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.myImage ( imageData ) VALUES ( @imageData )
```

#### Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myImage](
    [imageData] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL
)
```